# Convert Quartz Job Definitions from XML to Datasource

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I'm currently using Quartz for my job-scheduling tasks by configuring them via `jobs.xml` with the following line in `quartz.properties` file:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

Now, I would like to store my jobs in a data source. I've changed the `quartz.properties` file as follows:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
```

I also did all other configuration changes both in `quartz.properties` and my database, and get everything work. The thing is, all my jobs and triggers are written in `jobs.xml` and I need to import them to database somehow.

The only solution I can come up with is to create jobs and triggers via Java code and schedule everything again. However if there is something like importing all jobs and triggers to database by reading `jobs.xml` file, it would be great.

Does any one know if there is something like that? I'm aware I can write a program to do this, but still if there is already a implemented one, I'd like to utilize it.

Thanks